# Interop with existing Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, winapi, media-player

I've been digging around and wasn't able to pinpoint how to play a specific video in Windows Media Player.

Using WM_Command's I've been able to play/pause an existing video but haven't found a way to play a specific video file via Windows Messages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use DirectX AudioVideoPlayback:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324497(VS.85).aspx

```
[C#]using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;
public class MyVideoPlayer : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    /* ... */
    private void OpenFile()
    {
        try
        {
            Video ourVideo = new Video("C:\\Example.avi");
            /* ... */
        }
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: interesting, will this play in Windows Media Player or default media player?

Comment: API doesn't detail though I believe will be the default. The advantage is that DirectX is maybe omnipresent and plus you can get specific objects like Video.Audio to manage audio stream properties (volume and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WMP instance in your app then [undock the player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via IWMPPlayerApplication::switchToPlayerApplication.